# How to disable web pack in Angular 14

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-4, angular14

How to disable web pack in Angular 14 ?

I am not able to debug my code.

Angular JSON

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "color-admin": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
                "lodash"
            ],
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "src/scss/angular.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "color-admin:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "color-admin:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "color-admin:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets",
              "src/favicon.ico"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "color-admin-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "color-admin:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "color-admin",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "style": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

My Package Json -

```
{
  "name": "color-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "node remove-css-imports.js ngcc"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~14.2.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/localize": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.2.0",
    "@fullcalendar/angular": "^5.11.2",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/resource-timegrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.3",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^6.0.2",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
    "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^11.0.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-charts": "^20.1.0",
    "@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^20.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.15",
    "@yaireo/tagify": "^4.16.4",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.30.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "bootstrap-icons": "^1.9.1",
    "bootstrap-social": "^5.1.1",
    "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "core-js": "^3.25.0",
    "d3": "^7.6.1",
    "dart-sass": "^1.25.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.2",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "fibers": "^5.0.3",
    "flag-icon-css": "^4.1.6",
    "ionicons": "^6.0.3",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.1",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
    "lity": "^2.4.1",
    "masonry-layout": "^4.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-apexcharts": "^1.7.1",
    "ng-chartjs": "^0.2.5",
    "ng-masonry-layout": "^8.0.2",
    "ng2-nvd3": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-color": "^8.0.3",
    "ngx-countdown": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^6.0.2",
    "ngx-editor": "^15.0.0",
    "ngx-highlight-js": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-highlightjs": "^7.0.1",
    "ngx-masonry": "^13.0.0",
    "ngx-nvd3": "^1.0.9",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "^10.1.1",
    "ngx-trend": "^8.0.0",
    "nvd3": "^1.8.6",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.5.6",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.5.5",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.32",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.8.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.8"
  }
}
```

tsConfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "module": "es2020",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "paths": { "@angular/*": ["../node_modules/@angular/*"] }
  }
}
```

**main.ts**

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**pollyfills.ts -**

```
/***************************************************************************************************
 * Load `$localize` onto the global scope - used if i18n tags appear in Angular templates.
 */
import '@angular/localize/init';
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html
 */

/***************************************************************************************************
 * BROWSER POLYFILLS
 */

/** IE9, IE10 and IE11 requires all of the following polyfills. **/
// import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
// import 'core-js/es6/object';
// import 'core-js/es6/function';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
// import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
// import 'core-js/es6/number';
// import 'core-js/es6/math';
// import 'core-js/es6/string';
// import 'core-js/es6/date';
// import 'core-js/es6/array';
// import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
// import 'core-js/es6/map';
// import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
// import 'core-js/es6/set';

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

/** IE10 and IE11 requires the following for the Reflect API. */
// import 'core-js/es6/reflect';


/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.



/**
 * Required to support Web Animations `@angular/platform-browser/animations`.
 * Needed for: All but Chrome, Firefox and Opera. http://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation
 **/
// import 'web-animations-js';  // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.



/***************************************************************************************************
 * Zone JS is required by default for Angular itself.
 */
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';  // Included with Angular CLI.
```

/***************************************************************************************************

- APPLICATION IMPORTS
  */

Each and every time I ran my application, its bundled it and run it inside webpack. I am not able to debug my code.

I want some setting where I can enable and disable the webpack.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using `ng build` instead of `ng serve`? After using last one, accessing localhost:4200 (by default) should work

Comment: @DiegoN. - I am using, ng serve

Comment: @DiegoN. - I am not able to debug my code. Following the template of color admin. 
https://seantheme.com/color-admin/admin/html/index_v3.html